# Custom Math.Round

Tags: c#, .net, math, rounding

I want to round to 4 decimals and if anything after that is higher than 0 then round up to the next number.

Example:

```
 2.34121 ->  2.3413
50.58020 -> 50.5802
 4.49238 ->  4.4924
 0.00001 ->  0.0001
```

And Math.Round can round only from midpoint to up or down.

Comment: Seems like you want `Math.Ceil(10000*x)/10000`

Comment: @GiladGreen trading sites are rounding like this

Comment: @GiladGreen because the last digit is greater than 0.

Comment: How about `double result = ((int)(value*10000+9)/10000.0);`

Comment: What if you add 0.00004 before rounding?

Comment: @TurtlesAllTheWayDown good point

Comment: @TurtlesAllTheWayDown Presumably the OP would want 0.000001 rounded to 0.0001 instead of 0.

Comment: @juharr I have tested and by adding 0.00004 to the number seems to work even if the number is 0.00001

Comment: @TurtlesAllTheWayDown please add your answer so I can chose your answer.

Comment: @MarioM My example is not the same as your's.  It's 5 zeros between the decimal and the 1 not 4.  If you meant if the 5th digit is greater than 0 round up then yes, but you said if "anything" after the 4th was larger, so that's how I interrupted your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add 0.00004 before rounding.

Comment: and then Math.Round(number, 4)

Comment: What result do you get if you try this with `number=0.10021`? For me, it ends up rounding down to `0.1002`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson you are right, but if you add 0.000041 then it will work in any case

Comment: No, not in any case. How about `number=0.10020001`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
double CustomRound(double x) => Math.Ceiling(x * 10000) / 10000;
```

Comment: but the number may get to high if let's say I have 100,000,000.43821 multiplying that by 10000, may get too big to be holded by double

Comment: @MarioM You can use `decimal` in this case

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static double Convert(this double d)
    {
        var d1 = (int)(d * 10000);
        var d2 = (int)((d * 1000) * 10);
        if ((d1 - d2) != 0)
        {
            return Math.Round(d, 4) + 0.0001;
        }

        return Math.Round(d, 4);
    }
}
```

and then call `2.34121.Convert();`